# How to disable or enable virtual keyboard for certain devices?

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm making an app for three different devices, Honeywell EDA50, EDA50K and EDA60k, the last two has hardware keyboard while i've started to develop the app for EDA50 so i have lot of edittexts that show the keyboard on focus but now i would be able by checking the device name with the following code:

```
   public static String getDeviceName() {
        String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
        String model = Build.MODEL;
        if (model.startsWith(manufacturer)) {
            return capitalize(model);
        }
        return capitalize(manufacturer) + " " + model;
    }
```

i would be able to disable the virtualkeyboard for entire app if the device is EDA50K or EDA60K.

I've yet tryed to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) answer but nothing there are times when anyway the keyboard popup.

Is there any possibility to disable virtual keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();

if (view == null) {
    view = new View(activity);
}

imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

read full answer:
[Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Comment: that's not working, like in my mainactivity i have a button that open an alertDialog and when i'm trying to use your method that open the vkeyboard anyway